# MVC: функционирование, передача данных, генерация страниц

Tags: php, mvc

Изучая принцип `MVC`, я делал так: есть переменная `view`, которая получает некоторое значение и методом `get` это значение передается странице `index.php` Например: `index.php?view=articles&id=4`. Далее, `index.php`, анализируя гет-переменные, генерирует ту или иную страницу. Однако, глядя на сайты (и на хэшкод), я этого не вижу. В адресной строке находится что-то типа  `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/`, стало быть ссылка на внутренний `index.php`.

Каким образом это все функционирует? Как происходит передача данных и генерация страниц?

Comment: обычно используют фреймворки, например CodeIgniter вообще по умолчанию работает именно с такими url, вот демка как подобное сделать за 5 минут
http://doduts.comoj.com/ (а да волшебное слово - RewriteRule )

Comment: фреймворки это хорошо, демка непонятна. Как это работает? Я могу в ссылке прописать <a href="somesite/dir/otherpage/>переход</a>. Но как otherpage/index.php "узнает про шапку, подвал сайта и вообще,что ему генерировать. Мне бы принцип этой работы узнать.

Comment: в демке есть Archive там все есть, вас интересует файл router.php, 

- правда, Deus, в том, что никакого otherpage/index.php не существует

Comment: Я понял мне нужно разобраться с этим всем и станет все понятно?

Comment: с чем *этим всем* ? там кода 59 строчек

Comment: Я че спросил, начал делать сайт. Только было взялся за привычное view=что-то, пригляделся - ни фига такое нигде не используется. Блин, все, что изучаешь, тут же этого оказывается мало, либо все делается по-другому.

Comment: *я знаю всё - я ничего не знаю.* добро пожаловать в ноосферу :)

Comment: Я  не могу врубиться, как это у вас получается в комментариях редактировать текст, ну italic писать, например? ))

Comment: @Deus, в *комментариях* текст оформляется **точно так же как и в ответах/вопросах**.  
Ознакомиться можете в `?`, расположенном в ряду инструментов `wmd`-редактора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если с ангийским более менее терпимо, то могу поркомендовать прочитать вот этот цикл статей http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1 там 12 частей, рассказывается как создать собственный фреймворк на базе компонентов Symfony2, также все ключевые моменты: автозагрузка классов, запрос-ответ, **роутинг**, работа с событиями.

Ваш вопрос это - **роутинг**.